# Wordpress Theme Update Action?

Tags: functions, actions

I've done quite a bit of searching. I'm looking for hook/action called after a theme update. I know the initialization one - but a basic update? Cannot seem to find.

If one does not exist, how can you run a function after auto-updating?

Answer (score 3):

I have never tried to do what you are trying to do, so no promises, but there is an action hook called [`upgrader_process_complete`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L820) in the `upgrade` method of the `Theme_Upgrader` class, and it look like it would do what you want. The action is called like:

```
do_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', $this, array( 'action' => 'update', 'type' => 'theme' ), $theme )
```

So it looks like that `$this` parameter should have the information you need.

There is also an [`upgrader_post_install`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L261) hook in the parent `WP_Upgrader` class. That might be useful.